# Dual boot Windows 10 + Kali

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, kali-linux

On my computer I have two operating systems installed, Windows 10 and Kali Linux. The problem is that they are on separate bootloaders and on separate hard drives. I want to be able to add one of the operating systems to the other bootloader so that I can boot both operating systems from the same bootloader.

**What I have tried**

1) Using EasyBCD on Windows 10, that brings this message and prevents me from adding a Linux entry.

[image]

2) Using `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sbd4` (sbd4 has Win10 on it)

The `update-grub` doesn't detect Windows 10 and add it even if `os-prober` is run before hand.

The `grub-install /dev/sbd4` prints the following output

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `nfts` doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install
```

3) Writing a manual entry into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` like so

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
set root='(hd1, msdos4)'
chainloader +1
}
```

Produces the following output when `update-grub` is run

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
error: out of memory.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 203
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
```

I don't know what else to do/try to make the operating systems go on the same bootloader. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think one bootloader can only handle either EFI or Legacy. This is definitely true if on the same harddrive, and I don't think the behaviour changes when on two drives. If I am correct in this, you should reinstall Windows in legacy mode, or install kali-linux in EFI mode https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux

Comment: @BramMooij I'm looking to reinstall windows 10 in legacy mode but how do I do that? I can't seem to find a way to do it

Comment: If your BIOS can be set to legacy mode only it cannot be installed in EFI mode. Also it should list the mode in the boot menu. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode

Comment: @BramMooij I tried this but I got `We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one` when I tried to install

Comment: You probably have to fully wipe it first, perhaps under linux.